# NN: Why does the manual implementation converges better than Keras/TF?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I've [implemented](https://github.com/MaverickMeerkat/MachineLearningPython/blob/master/ex4/NN.py) a basic 1-hidden layer NN to identify digits from part of the MNIST dataset (This is adapted from the Coursera ML course). It is implemented using matrices and conjugated-gradient (fmincg) optimization.

In addition I've implemented both a [Keras implementation](https://github.com/MaverickMeerkat/MachineLearningPython/blob/master/ex4/KerasImplementation.py) and a vanilla [TF implementation](https://github.com/MaverickMeerkat/MachineLearningPython/blob/master/ex4/TFImplementation.py).

In the manual implementation, there's 50 iterations (or epochs, but since I'm using the whole batch, each epoch is of size 1).

Now, what I've noticed, is that the manual implementation takes a while to compute, but after 50 iterations gives me really good results.

Keras and TF on the other hand, takes less time to compute, but need about 500-1000 iterations if I'm using the whole batch to give me the same results. (Though using 50 epochs, with each processing mini-batches of size 32, seems to work good as well)

So I wonder, how come the manual impl. converges better? And why does it take longer to compute even though it's the same number of iterations (50)?

Comment: I can assume this has got something to do with the step size / learning-rate of the different optimizers.

Comment: fmincg starts with steps of 1, and then changes it, while keras/tf use a constant learning rate of 0.001